# SimpleDateFormat Parsing error with jQueryUI datepicker

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse date value using SimpleDateFormat from jQueryUi datepicker, but everytime I try to save it to the database it gets saved in a weird format, for instance I enter 02/10/1995 it gets saved as 0002-Jan-01.

```
try {
        Date albumRelease = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(request.getParameter("AlbumRelease"));
        album.setAlbumRelease(albumRelease);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


<label>Release Date</label>
<input type="text" name="AlbumRelease" id="datepicker" value="<fmt:formatDate pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" value="${album.albumRelease}" />" />
```

**variable check in debug mode returns albumRelease as "Sun Dec 27 00:00:00 IST 11"**

And I get a breakpoint error at AlbumController on line number 60)

https://github.com/linuxsavvy/music-library/blob/master/com.solancer/src/com/solancer/controller/AlbumController.java

https://github.com/linuxsavvy/music-library/blob/master/com.solancer/WebContent/Album.jsp

Comment: Shouldnt you be using `SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")` then if the input `String` is `02/10/1995`?

Comment: oh sorry that was a test code, but I'm using MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: In the servlet, how are you getting the request parameter value?

Comment: Moreover, I think `parse` method takes two arguments like this. `new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(request.getParameter("AlbumRelease"), new ParsePosition(0));`. Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli request.getParameter("AlbumRelease");

Comment: I was asking about the format. Are you getting in the same way as you are giving input? i.e., `02/10/1995`?

Comment: @RavindraGullapalli no it doesn't get saved the way I enter it.

Comment: try adding a log to see what are you getting from the frontend

Comment: My qn is if you do `System.out.println(request.getParameter("AlbumRelease"));` what is the output are you getting?

Comment: I did a variable check in debug mode which returned albumRelease value as "Sun Dec 27 00:00:00 IST 11"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are getting `Sun Dec 27 00:00:00 IST 11` in the servlet,

You have to use `SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yy")` instead of `SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")` in the servlet.